# Print Preview not displaying file

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a menu strip Print Preview event. i worked out the following procedure to view a pdf file located in the same path as my workbook.

```
    Private WithEvents docPrint As New PrintDocument()
' Declare a string to hold the entire document contents. 
Private documentContents As String

' Declare a variable to hold the portion of the document that 
' is not printed. 
Private stringToPrint As String

Private Sub ReadDocument()

    Dim xlWBPath As String = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Dim docName As String = xlWBPath & "\" & "CustomRanges.pdf"

    docPrint.DocumentName = docName

    Dim stream As New FileStream(docName, FileMode.Open)
    Try
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
        Try
            documentContents = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Finally
            reader.Dispose()
        End Try
    Finally
        stream.Dispose()
    End Try
    stringToPrint = documentContents

End Sub

Private Sub prnPrvStripCustomRange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles prnPrvStripCustomRanges.Click


    ReadDocument()
    prnPrvCustomRanges.Document = docPrint
    prnPrvCustomRanges.ShowDialog()


End Sub
```

The dialog pops up on click, but my document page is blank.   I have another event for printing and that one prints the same document. So I don't understand what I am doing wrong on my preview.

Here is my print procedure:

```
Private Sub prnCustonPages_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles prnCustonPages.Click

Dim xlWBPath As String = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim docName As String = xlWBPath & "\" & "CustomRanges.pdf"


docPrint.DocumentName = docName

prnPrtCustomRanges.Document = docPrint
prnPrtCustomRanges.PrinterSettings = docPrint.PrinterSettings
prnPrtCustomRanges.AllowSomePages = True

If prnPrtCustomRanges.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    docPrint.PrinterSettings = prnPrtCustomRanges.PrinterSettings
    docPrint.Print()


End If
```

End Sub

Comment: What will be visible in the preview is generated by your PrintDocument.PrintPage event handler.  You forgot to write one.

Comment: @Hans I added the PrintDocument.PrintPage but nothing.  Here is what I did. > Sub docPrint_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles docPrint.PrintPage

        prnPrtCustomRanges.Document = docPrint
        prnPrtCustomRanges.PrinterSettings = docPrint.PrinterSettings
        prnPrtCustomRanges.AllowSomePages = True

    End Sub

Comment: This just isn't close.  At least try the sample code you find in the MSDN Library article for the PrintPage event.

Comment: @hansPassant I will check it out and see what I can find. Thanks.